# Code on button press is blocking Kivy gui

Tags: python, kivy

I am just a beginner with python stuff. I wanted to create a gui with kivy to display images I downloaded from a website, but when I execute code after a button click (`on_download`), the gui freezes.
I found solutions to execute code with asyncio, threading etc, to avoid blocking code, but I do not know how to apply those to techniques for kivy. My goal is to press the download button, show some progress in the UI and while doing this, the window should be still movable, scalable etc. Current I get the message "program not responding", when I try to move the window to a different position while `download_images` is executed.

```
# gui.py

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

# my own class
from download import Downloader

class MainLayout(FloatLayout):

    def on_download(self):
        downloader = Downloader()
        url = self.ids.url_input.text
        downloader.download_images(url)


class DownloaderApp(App):
    pass


DownloaderApp().run()
```

The .kv file:

```
# downloader.kv

MainLayout:

<MainLayout>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        TextInput:
            id: url_input
            hint_text: "Enter URL"
            write_tab: False
            multiline: False
            on_text_validate: root.on_download()

        Button: 
            id: download_button
            text: "Download"
            width: "150dp"
            size_hint: None, 1
            on_press: root.on_download()
```

My own python class to download images:

```
# downloader.py

from pyppeteer import launch

class Downloader:
    async def download_images(self, url):
        browser = await launch(headless=True)
        page = browser.newPage()
        await page.goto(url, {'waitUntil' : 'domcontentloaded'})
        # get the content of a separate .js file to be executed in the browser
        script = self.get_script()
        # get infos about images on that page
        infos = await page.evaluate(script)
        # etc

    def convert_images(self, images):
        # TODO
        pass
    
    def get_script(self):
        # get content of .js file
        pass
```

Comment: Please re-edit your code according to `python` syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I hope I fixed all mistakes

Comment: You can use `thread` on that specific task `on_download` or within it. There is another python library [`requests`](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) for such stuff. In that case you may have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70524009/how-to-update-kivy-progress-bar-value-from-new-thread/70536736#70536736).

Comment: So I would run the call `downloader.download_images(url)` in another thread?

Comment: Yes, give it a try.